# Lmms missing vestige on ubuntu 20.04 lts

Tags: apt, software-installation, 20.04

I am trying to install lmms, but it is always missing the vestige plugin.
How can I install lmms with vestige?

Answer (score 0):

To use the Vestige plugin, you have to install via AppImage on Ubuntu 20.04.

Go to [the LMMS downloads page](https://lmms.io/download#linux) and click the Linux 64 Bit LMMS 1.2.2 button.

That will download `lmms-1.2.2-linux-x86_64.AppImage`

In order to run it, you will first need to make it executable

`chmod +x ./lmms-1.2.2-linux-x86_64.AppImage`

from there you can run it with `./lmms-1.2.2-linux-x86_64.AppImage`